# Why is the convergence mode in Central Limit Theorem convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability

I was watching the proof of CLM in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuUeWCjYGyU). Basically, the idea is that as sample size goes to infinity, the limit of the characteristic function converges to the characteristic function of a normal distribution.

My question is why is this convergence convergence in distribution?

Comment: Convergence in distribution is about as weak as it couldnbe. What stronger mode of convergence would you hope for?

Comment: Characteristic functions and CDF's have a one-to-one correspondence. So convergence of characteristic functions can be seen as convergence of the corresponding distribution. A formal theorem is called the Levy's cont. theorem.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer  that is exactly what i am looking for. If you can put that as an answer, i will accept it. fyi, you might be able to provide a good answer to this question as well. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283325/what-is-the-practical-implication-of-different-convergence-mode-of-random-variab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characteristic functions and cumulative distribution functions (CDF's) have a one-to-one correspondence. This one-to-one relationship can be seen from the inversion formula for the characteristic functions.

So convergence of characteristic functions can be seen as convergence of the corresponding distribution. A formal theorem is called the [Levy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).